# How to share property between multiple pages / pass by reference in navigation?

Tags: c#, .net, navigation, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am writing a UWP program, and I wish to share a common property/field between multiple pages. I tried to create a model(or maybe viewmodel) instance in the parent page and pass the instance to the children page as a parameter of `Frame.Navigate` method. However, since parameters in C# are passed by value, and Frame.Navigate does not support reference or out, I expect it does not work to actually share this instance between multiple pages.

My questions are

1. Is this the common practice for sharing values between pages, and will it work?
2. If not, what is the suggested approach?
3. If it is, why does it work?

Comment: Frame.Navigate(typeof(Mainpage), item),  by using this you can pass parameter to pages. What problem you are facing in this method?

Comment: @MohanvelV As I said, I wish the item could pass by reference. Is it possible, if not, how to share an object behind multiple pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share same values of one model between multiple pages then make your model as static class. So that they will share single copy of it.

Comment: I know this is a possible solution, but is it well-structured, and is it a common practice?

Comment: Yes it is. Static class it self has meaning to share single copy in whole application. Also it will initiate only one object so memory consumption is handling proper.

Comment: But if sharing of values may differ on bases of login then static class is not an option. Because static class will share same value irrespective of any login.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is modified page by page then you can pass the object of the model and can retrieve the same in OnNavigatedTo of the next page

```
 ItemModel objEditItem;
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Parameter != null)
        {
            objEditItem = new ItemModel();
            objEditItem = e.Parameter as ItemModel;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But this is apparently too complicated, and I think it isn't good for the performance since an object can be very big.